# How do I set a Machine environment variable from a Chocolatey package?

Tags: powershell, escaping, environment-variables, chocolatey

I'm the author of several Chocolatey packages that need to set environment variables as part of the proper "installation" of the package. For example: `ANT_HOME`, `MW_HOME`, and `JAVA_HOME` in the Java ecosystem should point to the installation directory for ant, weblogic, and java, respectively.

And, since Chocolatey is a machine-wide package manager, my thought would be to set these machine-wide ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "path/to/jre/install", "Machine")
```

If I just run that, I get the expected permission exception

> Exception calling "SetEnvironmentVariable" with "3" argument(s): "Requested registry access is not allowed."

If I run the same command in an elevated prompt, manually, everything works fine. So, I need to invoke it in an elevated prompt. With Chocolatey, you're supposed to use: `[Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin][2]` like so

```
Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin @"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "path/to/jre/install", "Machine")
"@
```

It prompts for elevation (I always run in a normal prompt when developing to be sure that it's actually working), but I see red errors flash by and this message with no warning/error

> Elevating Permissions and running C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "& import-module -name  'C:\Chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; try{[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", "path/to/jre/install", "Machine"); start-sleep 6;}catch{write-error 'That was not sucessful';start-sleep
>    8;throw;}". This may take awhile, depending on the statements.

What gives?

---

**UPDATE:**

Some combination of the following makes it work, mysteriously... adding line-terminators (even to single statements) and wrapping all the arguments in single quotes.

```
Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin @"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JAVA_HOME', 'path/to/jre/install', 'Machine');
"@
```

I would still like a non-brute-force answer. I'm sure it's a combination of PowerShell's nightmare string quoting/interpreting rules + Chocolatey's invocation.

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm also having trouble with multiple statements, even though I'm separating them!

```
Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin @"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MW_HOME', 'path/to/wl/install', 'Machine');
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('WL_HOME', 'path/to/wl/install/wlserver', 'Machine');
"@
```

I saw, but did not capture, a Chocolatey log statement on screen that showed one of the line-terminators removed!

---

**THOUGHT:**

I mean, should I just not do this and write an easy "User" environment variable instead? It's not correct! The damn things are installed machine-wide... I don't want to give up yet.

Comment: Ugh, my update appears to be flakey, too! If I manually execute it in a regular session, it works. If I let Chocolatey run it, it seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the [built in helper](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersReference#wiki-administrative-access-packages) for this, [`Install-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable`](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyEnvironmentVariable). The usage is quite simple...

```
Install-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable 'JAVA_HOME' 'path\to\jre' 'Machine'
```

Comment: Because I'm not current on my helpers and I didn't know this existed!